# How can I do synchronous test or not sharing a stub service?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angular, jasmine

I have a few tests that needs a service. I am using a stub service named `UserServiceStub` that I inject in my `SettingsComponent`, which I am testing. I reset the UserServiceStub in each test, but, tests are executed asynchronous so when I reset my UserServiceStub (which is an injectable and singleton class) other test has already initialized it. My tests are weak and asserts are wrong :-(

I would like to do synchronous test or a different UserServiceStub instance for each test, but I don't know how to do it...

I tried to define a method in UserServiceStub called `reset()` that resets stub service, but because it's asynchronous it doesn't work. Also, I executed in `afterEach()` method,  the `TestBed.resetTestEnvironment()` method but it does not work either.

My `reset()` method:

```
reset() {
    this.user = { IBAN: '', SWIFT: '', paypal: '', app_idioma: '' };
  }
```

- The property I am using is called `user` and it has being overwritten by other tests

My `beforeEach()` method is this one

```
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<SettingsComponent>;
 let settingsComponent: SettingsComponent;
 beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SettingsComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        TranslateService,
        AppService,
        { provide: MockBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
        { provide: HttpToolsService, useValue: HttpToolsServiceStub },
        { provide: BaseRequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions },
        { provide: UserService, useClass: UserServiceStub } // My stub UserService
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SettingsComponent);
    settingsComponent = fixture.componentInstance;

  });
```

A test:

```
 it('#updateSettings should  doesn\'t update the user\'s settings when is wrong', fakeAsync(
    inject([UserService, HttpToolsService, MockBackend],
      (userService: UserServiceStub, httpToolsService: HttpToolsService, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
        userService.reset(); // It does not work...
        userService.isError = true;
// However, I have reseted my user in UserServiceStub,
// this returns false because settingsComponent.getSettings().IBAN is actually 'XXX' 
// instead of '' (empty) how it has to be
        expect(settingsComponent.getSettings().IBAN).toBe(''); 
      }))
  );
```

I hope your answers, if you got any question just ask.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using getter/setter? This way value of `UserServiceStub.user` won't be modified (if I understood correctly what you want).

```
class UserServiceStub {
  // instead of:
  // this.user = { IBAN: '', SWIFT: '', paypal: '', app_idioma: '' };
  // use:
  get user() { return { IBAN: '', SWIFT: '', paypal: '', app_idioma: '' }; }
  set user(value) { /* test something here */ }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not what I need. Each `user` has different information in each test, but, when a test finishs, UserServiceStub saves the info of the latest test and while a test is being executed, in other test UserServiceStub has changed and I need an UserServiceStub different for each test. I hope you understand.